# sorting objects by multiple column Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I am trying to order my listing object by two column, the `created_at` column and a `popularity` column. The `popularity` column is either equal to 1 => popular listing or 0  = > normal listing.

I'd like listings to be ordered in a way that will put any popular listing at the top first (taking into account `created_at`).

I have a `search` variable which contains a collection of listing object (here is one of them):

```
#<Listing:0x007fe4031f2540
  id: 7,
  title: "",
  description: "test description",
  full_address: nil,
  neighborhood_id: nil,
  created_at: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:51:47 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:53:07 EDT -04:00,
  slug: "252-7th-ave-6e",
  bedrooms: 3,
  bathrooms: 3,
  sqft: 1200,
  lat: 40.7453,
  lng: -73.9955,
  price: 2500,
  available_date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015,
  status: "available",
  apartment: "6e",
  street_address: "252 7th Ave",
  zip_code: "10001",
  user_id: 41,
  rooms: 7,
  building_type: nil,
  showing: "Monday around 6pm",
  landlord_phone: "91780322202",
  landlord_email: "cghazanfar10@gmail.com",
  landlord_detail: "",
  landlord_name: "Cyrus",
  internal_notes: "",
  active_at: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:53:07 EDT -04:00,
  landlord_id: 4,
  building_id: 7,
  video_viewings: nil,
  deposit: 3000,
  normalized_address: "252 7th Ave",
  contact_phone: nil,
  min_income: nil,
  min_credit: nil,
  lease_id: nil,
  tenant_fee: 1200,
  security: 2500,
  other_fees: nil,
  fee_descriptions: "",
  listing_type: "full",
  popularity: 0>
```

I've tried `search.order("popularity DESC, created_at DESC")` but that doesn't seem to meet both criteria which is: order by the popular listing first disregarding the fact that their `created_at` date might be before other non popular listing; then just sort by `created_at` in desc order.

Comment: What if you reverse the sort arguments? Sort by `created_at` first, then by `popularity`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the thing is `created_at` will then take precedence over `popularity`. I need listings with an attribute popularity equal to 1 to be the first and foremost listings. Good thinking though ;)

Comment: Look on the SQL generated by your query, the Rails part looks totally correct.

Comment: Has the `search` already gone through an `order`? If so, the second `order` will not have any effect. Try `search.reorder(popularity: :desc, created_at: :desc)`

Comment: Excellent @AbM that actually work. And yes you're right search was already ordered before hand, so `reorder` solved the problem.